"failed to enable keyboard on isa0060/serio0"
I upgraded Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04 but since then my keyboard have been misbehaving. At the start up page it is displaying "failed to enable keyboard on isa0060/serio0"
I am running it on Toshiba satellite-pro laptop
